# how to remove object in javascript with conditional statement

Tags: javascript

> Im trying to remove all object if the `frequency > total_payment` if true remove it from object if false not be remove...

```
   const deductions = this.payrollPayableArray.reduce((c,o)=>({
                ...c,
                ...o.deduction,                
              }),{})
              Object.keys(deductions).filter((key)=>{
                if(key == null || key == '') delete deductions[key]
              })


                   Object.values(deductions).reduce((key,item)=>{
                if(item.frequency > item.total_payment) delete deductions[key]     <-- not working
              })
              this.DeductionArray = deductions
                 })  
            }){
```

> Result of my code not working I hope you can help me all answers I will appreciate...

```
   "1": {
    "total_payment": 29,
    "frequency": 10,
    "amount": 500,
  },
  "4": {
    "total_payment": 27,
    "frequency": 1,
    "amount": 500,
  },
  "5": {
    "total_payment": 27,
    "frequency": 6,
    "amount": 483.33,
  },
  "6": {
    "total_payment": 28,
    "frequency": 10,
    "amount": 222.2,
  },
  "7": {
    "total_payment": 1,
    "frequency": 2,
    "amount": 1000,

  }
}
```

> What I want to achieved...

```
 {
    "7": {
    "total_payment": 1,
    "frequency": 2,
    "amount": 1000,

  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use array `filter()`?

Comment: I try it but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try reduce function.

```js
const amounts = { 
   "1": { "total_payment": 29, "frequency": 10, "amount": 500 },
   "4": { "total_payment": 27, "frequency": 1, "amount": 500 },
   "5": { "total_payment": 27, "frequency": 6, "amount": 483.33 },
   "6": { "total_payment": 28, "frequency": 10, "amount": 222.2 },
   "7": { "total_payment": 1, "frequency": 2, "amount": 1000 }
}

const modifiedAmounts = Object.keys(amounts).reduce((acc, cur) => {
      const {frequency, total_payment } = amounts[cur];
      if(frequency > total_payment) acc[cur] = amounts[cur];

      return acc;
}, {})

console.log(modifiedAmounts)
```

```
const modifiedAmounts = Object.keys(amounts).reduce((acc, cur) => {
      const {frequency, total_payment } = amounts[cur];
      if(frequency > total_payment) acc[cur] = amounts[cur];

      return acc;
}, {})
```

modifiedAmounts:

```
{
  "7": {
    "total_payment": 1,
    "frequency": 2,
    "amount": 1000
  }
}
```

if you would want the result in array obj, you can change the reduce function acc to be an array.

```js
const amounts = { 
   "1": { "total_payment": 29, "frequency": 10, "amount": 500 },
   "4": { "total_payment": 27, "frequency": 1, "amount": 500 },
   "5": { "total_payment": 27, "frequency": 6, "amount": 483.33 },
   "6": { "total_payment": 28, "frequency": 10, "amount": 222.2 },
   "7": { "total_payment": 1, "frequency": 2, "amount": 1000 }
}

const modifiedAmounts = Object.keys(amounts).reduce((acc, cur) => {
      const {frequency, total_payment } = amounts[cur];
      if(frequency > total_payment) acc.push({[cur]: amounts[cur]});

      return acc;
}, [])

console.log(modifiedAmounts)
```

```
const modifiedAmounts = Object.keys(amounts).reduce((acc, cur) => {
      const {frequency, total_payment } = amounts[cur];
      if(frequency > total_payment) acc.push({[cur]: amounts[cur]});

      return acc;
}, [])
```

modifiedAmounts:

```
[
  {
    "7": {
      "total_payment": 1,
      "frequency": 2,
      "amount": 1000
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: But it convert in array so the index is 0 I want that the index is 7

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = {

    "1": {
        "total_payment": 29,
        "frequency": 10,
        "amount": 500,
      },
      "4": {
        "total_payment": 27,
        "frequency": 1,
        "amount": 500,
      },
      "5": {
        "total_payment": 27,
        "frequency": 6,
        "amount": 483.33,
      },
      "6": {
        "total_payment": 28,
        "frequency": 10,
        "amount": 222.2,
      },
      "7": {
        "total_payment": 1,
        "frequency": 2,
        "amount": 1000,
    
      }
}

const res  = Object.entries( items).filter(  ( [,deductions]  )=>{

return deductions.frequency > deductions.total_payment;
   
});

console.log( res);
```

//What about something similar to this?
const items = {

```
"1": {
    "total_payment": 29,
    "frequency": 10,
    "amount": 500,
  },
  "4": {
    "total_payment": 27,
    "frequency": 1,
    "amount": 500,
  },
  "5": {
    "total_payment": 27,
    "frequency": 6,
    "amount": 483.33,
  },
  "6": {
    "total_payment": 28,
    "frequency": 10,
    "amount": 222.2,
  },
  "7": {
    "total_payment": 1,
    "frequency": 2,
    "amount": 1000,

  }
```

}

const res  = Object.entries( items).filter(  ( [,deductions]  )=>{

return deductions.frequency > deductions.total_payment;

});